# can't understand second equation of triangle wave

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

[image]

the second equation f(t)=2A-(2A/T)t is written for the second slope of the triangle in the middle  "\" this slop of the middle triangle so it explained that this slope will intersect wit y axis in 2A amplitude and said that's why we should write first 2A on the equation above.but i cant understand it.Because in the first equation f(t)=(A/(T/2))t=(2A/T)t we derived amplitude by period by solving the equation there has to be some derivation of the very first 2A on the first formula not just the assumption that the amplitude is 2 times greater than the actual amplitude

Answer (score 0):

For the first equation, your professor is calculating slope in the sense "rise/run". That is, the rise (from the origin) is A, and the run is T/2.

For the second equation, it is as you stated. If you extend the downward sloping part of the triangle to intersect the y-axis, you will be at a height of 2A (the y-intercept). The slope is -(2A)/T because the triangle is symmetric. Or, you could define two points (T/2, A) and (T, 0) and find the slope that way.